# TableView Multiple Prototype Cell and number of rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to have multiple rows in the first prototype cell; the second cell must be static.

I tried to do it but I cant have the second prototype cell to be static. I am using a custom class for the cell:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

DetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ss"];
if (cell.tag == 0)
    return 8;
else if (cell.tag == 1)
    return 1;

else
    return 1;
}
```

Only the first one gets a return, and I do not even see these two buttons. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, unless you specify your UITableView to use static cells , you cannot use them. And you cannot mix prototype cells and static cells in single tableview.

According to your requirement, you should create two prototype cells instead of going for one cell as a static cell:

One Prototype  -> for your dynamic cells

Second Prototype -> for your static cell

Now change the TableView Datasource as follows :

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

    { 
        // suppose [self.dynamicArray count] = 8
        //Adding 1 for your static cell

        return [self.dynamicArray count] +  1;

    }
```

Suppose, you want to display the last cell with the second Prototype (static cell representation) then implement cellForRowAtIndexPath as :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
        if (indexPath.row < [self.dynamicArray count] ) 
        {
                // normal dynamic logic here
            NSString *cellIdentifier = @"DynamicCellID"
            // dequeue and configure for [self.dynamicArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
        } 
   //this will be the last cell in which you want the second  prototype cell acting as Static cell
   else  
   {
 // dequeue and configure my second prototype cell for indexPath.row
        NSString *cellIdentifier = ... // id for one of my static cells
    }
}
```

You can use the same logic for implementing different heights for the  two prototype cells in heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @Jeeny Jose Thnx for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

static NSString *cellIdentifier;

```
if(indexPath.section == 8)
{
cellIdentifier = @"Intake";
}
else
    cellIdentifier =@"CollegeDetail";

CollegeDetailCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[CollegeDetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```